# Error using react-map-gl in create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, mapbox-gl-js, create-react-app

Building a simple app to tryout Uber's [React Map GL](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl) using the super simple [Create React App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app) setup. Here's a simplified setup of what I have:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import MapGL from 'react-map-gl'

class Home extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MapGL
        width={400}
        height={400}
        latitude={37.7577}
        longitude={-122.4376}
        zoom={8}
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9"
      />
  }
}
```

which results in an error of:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
  at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
  at new module.exports (index.js:9)
  at Object.<anonymous> (web_worker.js:5)
  at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap e5da5fb…:555)
  at fn (bootstrap e5da5fb…:86)
  at Object.<anonymous> (worker_pool.js:4)
  at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap e5da5fb…:555)
  at fn (bootstrap e5da5fb…:86)
  at Object.<anonymous> (global_worker_pool.js:2)
  at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap e5da5fb…:555)
```

In looking at Uber's [example app using webpack](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl/tree/master/examples/exhibit-webpack) I noticed they're using the `transform-loader?brfs-babel` loader for the `mapbox-gl.js` file.

With Create React App you don't have access to the webpack configuration since it's contained within another package, so the only option seems to be to run `npm run eject` to pull the dependancies and webpack configuration into the project.

Is ejecting the only option? Or am I missing a way to do this within a standard `create-react-app` install?

Comment: i think issue is, `mapStyle`, it expect a style `object`, and u r passing a `string`, use it like this: `mapStyle={mapboxStyle}`, check the doc: https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl#transitions

Comment: That's what I thought too, but the Uber example app shows a `string` being used - https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl/blob/master/examples/exhibit-webpack/app.js#L32

Answer (score 1):

For development add mapboxApiAccessToken property.

If you're usin CRA, In production in .env file set REACT_APP_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN environmen varilable.
mapboxApiAccessToken={'process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN'}/>

```
<MapGL
        width={400}
        height={400}
        latitude={37.7577}
        longitude={-122.4376}
        zoom={8}
        mapStyle="mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v9"
        mapboxApiAccessToken={'your-access-toekn-goes-here'}/>
```